# A lot of bash.exe processes in Rammap taking up memory

Tags: windows-7, memory

My windows 7 installation started having a memory leak where after a few days memory usage slowly creeps up to 90% (of 16 gb).

In my task manager, the list of processes don't add up to that much memory, so I downloaded rammap and saw a bunch of bash.exe and sed.exe processes.

Each of these use up 4K. I uninstalled cygwin, but this is still happening:

[image]

Edit: Some more information: They do not come back immediately after a restart. However, after some more time memory usage starts going up again and I check RAMMAP and the weird processes are there again.

I don't have cygwin installed anymore, so it's curious where these are even coming from

Comment: I'm guessing the processes come back after a reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to find out from which folder these processes are coming from and what are their parameters by double-click on the process to display
its properties.

The folder-name will identify the installed product that is responsible
for these processes, and the parameters may indicate for what purpose.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just downloaded process explorer and unfortunately it doesn't show any of the "bash.exe" in there. I opened RamMap and still seeing those processes though.

Comment: Ah was able to finally find bash.exe in process explorer and saw that it was coming from Prey.exe. I uninstalled this program and it hasn't happened since then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have hardly provided enough information, but assuming these processes start up again after a reboot, you could probably prevent them from starting by using `msconfig`.

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and type in `msconfig`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Click `Yes` if asked whether to run the program (Don't we all love [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control)?)
3. Go to the `Startup` tab
4. Now comes the tricky part. Carefully look at each item (you may need to expand the window to see all the information), and if it starts anything that appears related to Cygwin, `bash.exe`, `sed.exe`, whatever, disable it.
5. Reboot
6. If your problem comes back, you can check `msconfig` again and see if you missed anything.

You can probably disable most of the `Startup` items safely, and if something quits working after you reboot, go back into `msconfig` and enable some of the things you disabled. Really, it isn't hard. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem seems a bug in a Windows 7 update delivered this summer. After installing this update, any process leaves 20 KB occupied. This seems not much, but when processes are called many times repeatedly, it can sum up to several GB (in my case, it's a build prcedure which calls hundreds of thousands of make.exe, bash.exe, sed.exe, sh.exe, g++.exe, cc1plus.exe etc. which adds ca. 8 GB to memory usage every night).